# CSS on optgroup (the header/label, not the options)

Tags: css, select, label, optgroup

I have a question that stay unanswered until now. Can't find similar topic on Internet I'm afraid.

I have some list :

```
<select class="class_blabla" onchange="js_blabla" id="id_blabla">
    <optgroup label="colors">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>  
        <option value="green">green</option>
    </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="numbers">
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>  
        <option value="three">3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I know how to apply a special CSS, on the optgroup label... But it's spreading to his option. How can I change **ONLY** the optgroup label/title, but not the options ? I can override the CSS of the options, but i would like this :

```
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #F8FAFD);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #F8FAFD);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #F8FAFD);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #F8FAFD);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E0E0E0, #F8FAFD);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#E0E0E0,#F8FAFD);
    border-bottom:1px #E0E0E0 solid;
```

gradient + border bottom

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452479/css-to-change-style-of-select-box-optgroup-label

Comment: Ok... I made it happens by removing the <optgroup>, and replacing them by normal <option>, where the CSS give us more options. And of course I made them unclickable.