# Styling group headers in angular property GROUP BY for ng-options in select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm using the angular 'GROUP BY' filter in my ng-options for my `<select>` tag. So, what I'd like to know is of a way to be able to add a the following style elements to the group headers:

```
font style: normal;
font weight: normal;
font-color: #b2b2b2;
```

This is the code snippet I want to implement this in, for reference:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <select chosen ng-options="location._id as location.name group by location.company.name for location in locations" ng-model="fl.locations" multiple="true"></select>
</div>"
```

Would appreciate any kind of help on this. And oh, i'd prefer it **NOT** be a Jquery solution and instead be some kind of a javascript or angular directive kind of a solution.
Thanks Again :)

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to use basic CSS to style the `optgroup` tag. I tried to do this in Firefox and it worked for style and weight, not the color though. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452479/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-select-box-optgroup-label

Comment: @ChrisG I have no <optgroup> tags, its ng-options and the date comes in from my server through a controller.

Comment: As explained in the answer you got, using `ng-options` and `group by` *creates* <optgroup> tags.

Comment: They're also shown when you use the inspector to check your source code, an essential tool for any dev.

Answer (score 0):

Angular renders `optgroup` HTML elements for each group in the `group by` expression.

So to style the groups, you just target the `optgroup` elements using CSS:

```
optgroup {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

However, these styles will cascade down to the child `option` elements as well. So you'll need to override any undesired styles for `option` as necessary:

```css
optgroup {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group A">
    <option>A1</option>
    <option>A2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group B">
    <option>B1</option>
    <option>B2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```